Easepick set booked dates from a variable in Lock plugin
I am using a date picker easepick and I'm trying to pass the dates through to javascript file and disable the dates that I am passing through. The problem is even if I try to set more than one date in a variable it only disables the first date.
This is an example from easepick however this is with hard coded dates inside easepick
 const bookedDates = [
          '2024-09-02',
          ['2024-09-06', '2024-09-11'],
          '2024-09-18',
          '2024-09-19',
          '2024-09-20',
          '2024-09-25',
          '2024-09-28',
      ].map(d => {
          if (d instanceof Array) {
            const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD');

            return [start, end];
          }

This is what I've tried
    if (datesUna == undefined) {
        date1 = '2024-09-19';
        date2 = '2024-09-21';
        datesUna = date1.concat(",",date2);
        console.log(datesUna);
    } else {
        datesUna = datesUna.replaceAll('"', '');
        console.log(datesUna);
    }

This is the concatinated string : 2024-09-19,2024-09-21
This is the console log for a string that I pass through from the backend :
'2024-09-07','2024-10-13','2024-10-14','2024-10-15','2024-10-16','2024-10-17','2024-10-18','2024-10-19','2024-10-20','2024-11-08','2024-11-09','2024-11-22','2024-11-23','2024-11-24','2024-11-25','2024-11-26','2024-12-04','2024-12-05','2024-12-06','2024-12-07','2024-12-23','2024-12-24','2024-12-25','2024-12-26','2025-04-23','2025-04-24','2025-04-25','2025-04-26','2025-05-22','2025-05-23','2025-05-24','2025-05-25','2025-05-26','2025-07-01','2025-07-02','2025-07-03','2025-07-04','2025-07-05','2025-07-06','2025-07-07','2025-07-08','2025-07-09','2025-07-10','2025-07-25','2025-07-26','2025-07-27','2025-07-28','2025-07-29','2025-07-30','2025-07-31','2025-08-01','2025-08-02','2025-08-03','2025-08-04','2025-08-05','2025-08-06','2025-08-07'
    const bookedDates = [datesUna].map(d => {
  if (d instanceof Array) {
    const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD');

    return [start, end];
  }

  return new DateTime(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
});

Even if I concat two dates only the date1 will be disabled and date2 won't be.

Can you please share the example link which you are referring  from easepick
